# Is it possible to get the first type of a parameter pack in a one-liner?

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, c++17

I have a parameter pack given in a variadic class template and want to extract the first type.

Currently I do this, which works fine but is somehow cumbersome. Is it possible to do the same thing simpler? `FirstEntityType` should be defined to have the type of the first type in `EntityTs`. Note, I want to keep the signature of the class template. I know that it would be possible to write `template<typename FirstEntityType, typename... OtherEntityTypes>`, it is however something that I don't want to do.

```
template<typename... EntityTs>
struct EntityContext
{
    template<typename T, typename ... Ts>
    struct K {
        using type = T;
    };

    using FirstEntityType = typename K<EntityTs...>::type;
    
   // ...
};
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You could write:

```cpp
using FirstEntityType = std::tuple_element_t<0, std::tuple<EntityTs...>>;
```

Or you could use Boost.Mp11:

```cpp
using FirstEntityType = mp_front<EntityContext>;
```

Comment: Is this SFINAE friendly, and if so in what version of C++?

Comment: @Yakk We're not in an immediate context, so doesn't matter?

Comment: How is the first solution supposed to be used?

Comment: @Enlico What do you mean how? Just... as-is.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, who know what the heck I was doing wrong.

Answer (score 12):

You may use

```
std::tuple_element<0, std::tuple<EntityTs...>>::type
```