# Checking that a template type T is part of a variadic parameter pack in C++17

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, c++17

I want to check that a type `T` is also part of a parameter pack `Ts`. There are [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19426045/how-can-you-statically-check-that-a-type-t-exists-in-a-variadic-template-paramet) that do that in C++14, but I'm wandering if this can be simplified in C++17. If `T` is not found in `Ts`the compiler should stop (static_assertion should fail).

```
template<typename... Ts>
class A
{
  template<typename T>
  void action() {
    // check that T is also in Ts (static_assertion)
  }
}
```

Comment: The solution you linked to is 5 lines long. How much simplification are you looking for?

Comment: My question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45578484/is-it-possible-to-get-the-first-type-of-a-parameter-pack-in-a-one-liner/45578533#45578533) had four working lines, the answer had only one. Solutions you find here for making a `tuple` of `vector`s of some types in a pack are longer than 10 lines. Its now doable in one.

Comment: @Sneftel, there you go. one-liner.

Comment: There I go indeed. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I hear fold-expressions are the new hotness:

```
static_assert((std::is_same_v<T, Ts> || ...));
```

Answer (score 5):

If you prefer a library trait:

```
static_assert(std::disjunction_v<std::is_same<T, Ts>...>);
```

Note that this performs short circuiting (perhaps not exceedingly beneficial here, but something to keep in mind). Fold expressions are equally viable:

```
static_assert((std::is_same_v<T, Ts> || ...));
```

(Stolen from @Barry.)

Answer (score 0):

Easy enough in C++ with fold expressions:

```
template<typename... Ts>
class A
{
  template<typename T>
  void action() {
    static_assert((... || std::is_same_v<T, Ts>)), "Not!")
  }
}
```